# How to force the shutdown of the PIC18

Tags: pic, voltage, assembly

I made a simple project, a "Hello World" test. The LED's light up, but when I turn the power off for the PIC18 they still stay on for a few seconds. I want to turn off the power to the PIC18 with no delay; is that possible?

Comment: You probably have a large capacitor on your board which keeps the LED and micro on for a while..

Comment: If you posted a circuit diagram for the complete circuit (including power switch and power supply), people would be able to suggest how to alter it to achieve what you want.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for the reply. On the power supply there are some capacitors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a comparator for VCC, and when it goes low use an interrupt to bring the program to a quick stop before the power goes totally out, instead of taking your chances with a cold power off.

Edit:
Might be a bit easier said than done, as Vcc for your comparator would also change.  You'd need to use a voltage regulator to generate Vcc from a higher voltage, then monitor Vsupply through voltage divider to keep it in range of the comparator.

Alternatively, if this is super-important and the above isn't suitable, you could switch to a microcontroller with better power monitoring tools.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for the reply. On the power supply there are some capacitors

Answer (score 0):

You can make an alternative way for the current to passa when you turn it off. As already said, probably you have some capacitors in your board (maybe in the power supply) that holds some charge and whenever you turn the power off, it still supplies some current to the circuit. You could create some mechanism to open an alternative path for your capacitor to discharge not through the circuit whenever you take off the power. But it depends on how is your circuit... you should give us more info but that is the pretty basic idea.

There are switches with multiple ways. So one thing you can do is to use one way to turn off power and other way to close a circuit/path of discharging the capacitor. Another method you can try is using one way of the switch to turn off the power and the other way to interrupt PIC's supply path.

Comment: Cara, tenta criar um caminho alternativo no circuito pra descarregar tudo sem ser pelo PIC. Provavelmente há algum capacitor em algum lugar (geralmente na fonte) que segura carga e descarrega quando tu desliga a fonte. O ideal seria botar, talvez no mesmo interruptor da fonte, um caminho pelo qual o capacitor pudesse descarregar todo, sem ter que usar o circuito com o PIC pra isso. Mas coloca aí umas imagens do teu circuito pra gente ver como é, dai fica mais facil de dizer como exatamente fazer isso.

Comment: Tem interruptores de multiplas vias, entao vc pode usar um interruptor desse e daí numa das vias vc passa o circuito da fonte (interrompe a fonte) e na outra via vc usa pra criar um caminho de descarga pro capacitor. Outra maneira é usar uma das vias ainda pra fonte e a outra pra cortar imediatamente a alimentaçao direta do PIC.

Comment: @clabacchio I thought the comments were your thoughts, but then I checked the revision history and saw that the text in the comments is the original answer content.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman I'm not that good with portuguese :) It's just to keep it tidier, but the translation might be useful to the op

Comment: @clabacchio obrigado pela tradução :) e realmente o problema era na fonte, nela existiam alguns capacitores que mesmo após eu desligando o circuito ainda permanecia ligado. "Problem solved. Thanks for the reply. On the power supply there are some capacitors ..."

Answer (score 0):

Lot of details are missing from your requirements, but seems that you need some way to actively reset the controller when the power supply is switched off. Here is a concept.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftkdqe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- R1, R2 and C1 must be sized in such a way that during voltage zero crossings the base current is sufficient to saturate the transistor;
- C2 must be sized such that the power supply ripple is sufficiently small for the regulator circuit;
- You probably need an inverter stage to invert \$RESET \text{ to } \overline{RESET}\$ to connect it to the \$\overline{RESET}\$-pin of your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to put it into practice. :)